# Strange min height behaviour

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with the following jquery min-height issue.
I have four toggled divs and a footer all are working fine, but the min-height is not in my control. Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-toggle").click(function () {
            var bodyHeight = parseInt($(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height'));
            var linkHeight = $(this).siblings('p.matter').height();
            var addHeight = bodyHeight + linkHeight;
            var subHeight = bodyHeight - linkHeight;
            var isOpen = false;
            if ($(this).siblings("p.matter").css("display") !== "none") {
                isOpen = true;
            }
            $("p.matter").slideUp();
            if (isOpen) {
                $(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height', subHeight);
                $(this).siblings("p.matter").slideUp();
            } else {
                $(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height', addHeight);
                $(this).siblings("p.matter").slideDown();
            }

        });//click fn end
    });//document end
```

for your convenience i made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7EZm6/).

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1. when ever continuous click on all four toggle links footer is going down and down.
(Sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script to the one below (you should se the parent div to bodyheight and not addedheigth)

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7EZm6/1/)

```
$(".btn-toggle").click(function () {
    var bodyHeight = parseInt($(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height'));
    var linkHeight = $(this).siblings('p.matter').height();
    var addHeight = bodyHeight + linkHeight;
    var subHeight = bodyHeight - linkHeight;
    var isOpen = false;
    if ($(this).siblings("p.matter").css("display") !== "none") {
        isOpen = true;
    }
    $("p.matter").slideUp();
    if (isOpen) {
        $(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height', subHeight);
        $(this).siblings("p.matter").slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).parents(".container-wrapper").css('min-height', bodyHeight);
        $(this).siblings("p.matter").slideDown();
    }

}); //click fn end
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, actually i need to add "addHeight" to "bodyHeigh" for my project.

Comment: is there any other solution with out changing the "addHeight" to "bodyHeight" in "else" part.

Comment: Do you mean like replacing bodyHeight with linkHeight in the else? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7EZm6/2/

Comment: exactly your solutions helped me alot in getting new ideas.... thanks for your help...